# Where to put the "al" command in order to generate the policy publisher assembly?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a publisher policy assemble in the Developer Command Prompt for VS 17, but it keeps giving me the same message: "AL1019: Metadata fail when creating the assembly .The system could not find the specified file."

I'm following a book(C# 6 and the .NET 4.6 Framework), which gives this line to do so: al /link:CarLibraryPolicy.xml /out:policy.1.0.CarLibrary.dll
/keyf:C:\MyKey\myKey.snk /v:1.0.0.0

This gives me the same message. I tried altering the "keyf" to the same path for the same snk file assigned to the dll for which I'm trying to build the publisher policy, since I read this in the MSDN. But the results are the same.

I thought of changing the version, but which version is that? The version of the target assembly or the version of the assembly that will be "bypassed"?

Which file is not being found? The dll or the snk? I imagine that the problem is where I'm typing the command, neither the MSDN, nor the book mentions that. I'm stuck in this for over a week and I can't get it to work.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the command would be typed in at either a dos or powershell prompt (if using Windows).  You will need the path to your tools in your 'PATH' variable or fully qualify the path to the 'al' command.  You might also take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz32563a(v=vs.110).aspx to see if that helps.  There is some discussion of a /platform argument and limitations using the v2.0 linker with earlier assemblies.